# Indicator Variable, Mixed Integer Linear Programming

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, integer-programming

Assume $x$ is a real variable, and $0\leq x \leq1$. Besides, $y$ is a binary random variable.

I need a linear program that:

if $y$ is $1$: $x>0$,

if $y$ is $0$: $x=0$

I know the following constraint forces $y$ to be $1$, if $x>0$. But, it does not force $x$ to be greater than $0$ if $y=1$.

$x\leq y$

How should I write the linear constraints to satisfy my objective?

Comment: It seems to me like you'll have a hard time writing linear constraints to enforce something of the form $x>0$ (with strict inequality).

Comment: Depending on your objective function, you may not have to enforce $y=1 \rightarrow x>0$? You may eventually enforce $y=1 \rightarrow x>= \epsilon$, with $\epsilon$ very small, but it is possible that it causes some numerical difficulties during the solution of the model based on linear programming relaxation.

Comment: Linear and convex programming cannot deal with strict inequalities. Unless you can offer a non-zero lower bound in the $y=1$ case, you are out of luck.

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your question to show us at least a portion of the larger model. Chances are you do not "need" to enforce strict inequality if you express the larger constraint differently.