# Sign of a Linear Expression in Mixed Integer Linear Programming

Tags: math-software, integer-programming

I have a question about a system in [mixed integer programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) I am trying to solve using [GLPK](https://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/) though the question mathematical and is software agnostic.

I have converted the whole problem to linear equations and inequalities except for one part. Suppose I have a real number $x$ and a binary variable $b$ (either 0 or 1). How can I "tie them together" such that $x > 0$ if and only if $b = 1$?

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1159730/indicator-variable-mixed-integer-linear-programming) seems to address a similar question but I am suspicious of the answers since I know ILP in NP-complete and the commentors don't seem to acknowledge it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$0.001 b \le x \le U b$$ 
where I assume $0 \le x \le U$.

I don't see how this particular formulation is related to NP-completeness. If you are worried about the complexity of this don't use a MIP model at all but rather use a heuristic (even this may be overstating things as state-of-the-art MIP solvers actually use lots of heuristics internally).